# Should there be separate tags for [bread] and [breadmaking]?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Currently I think the [bread] tag covers baking bread and using bread in cooking (and even a question about using bread as something to eat off).

Seems to me bread is a case where making it is different from using it as an ingredient and tags should reflect this distinction.

There may be other core foods where the same thing applies.

Also, is it expected (or even encouraged) that an ordinary member (albeit with 200 rep or whatever is required to retag) might implement this kind of global change (more or less feasible with the 20 or so bread questions which currently exist). Or is it a mod job?

Answer (score 4):

I don't see a need. The simple fact that there is nothing tagged `[breadmaking]` tells me that this is an attempt to fix a problem that does not yet exist.

The questions that are currently relevant to breadmaking are tagged with both `[bread]` and `[baking]`. I think that's sufficient.

Generally, *bulk* tag changes/merges should be discussed here for a moderator to perform.

Comment: sure there's no pressing need at the right now. but some of what we're doing currently is looking forward to a busier site and planning accordingly, no?

Comment: "Generally, bulk tag changes ..." agree with you on retagging approach in principle. makes sense

Comment: there's also the [dough] tag just to add to the mix

Comment: @Tea: There are plenty of useful tools available to those with the appropriate reputation to assist with tag management. I think it's a better use of resources to deal with tag issues as they arise, instead of as they are thought of.

Comment: @Tea Drinker @Hobodave.  That's true, in terms of dealing with synonyms, especially because the system *won't allow* creating a synonym for a tag until there actually *is* that tag on a real question.  But waiting too long doesn't make sense either because of the inability to retroactively merge tags.  So we should not do it preemptively, but we shouldn't wait until it's a problem either.

Comment: "the inability to retroactively merge tags" - This is incorrect. Such ability does exist and is available to moderators.