# Should we merge [bread] and [breadmaking]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

We actually had a [previous meta question](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/571/41) about this subject a very long time ago, in which the only response was that we shouldn't have separate tags to begin with.

Now we *do* have separate tags, and they've been confounded by last week's [bread question contest](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1296/41) in which almost every question was about bread-making but most were just tagged [bread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bread).

In my opinion, if there ever *was* any meaningful distinction between these tags, it has been completely and utterly lost to the ages.

Can we merge these and make them synonyms? Or are there *really* a statistically significant number of culinary questions about bread that aren't actually about making/baking bread?

It's not like we get a lot of questions about bread pudding or sandwich-making... right?

Comment: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/bread/synonyms ... one more person needs to vote it up...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, absolutely.  I don't think anybody looking to make bread is going to search the bread-making tag anyway.

Comment: I suggested a synonym, it just needs votes now. http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/bread/synonyms

Answer (score 1):

The tag synonym was proposed and accepted and the tags have now been merged.